# Why is the Add button to Assign a New Page Role disabled?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I want to add a person as an Editor to a Facebook Page but the Add button is disabled:
[image: Facebook Page Roles]

I tried with both the person's name and their email. I have the role of Admin in the page and there's one other Admin. Is there a limit on the number of people with roles or some other reason I can't add a person to the page? What else could I look for?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the person needs to already be following the page.

Comment: Please don't post use the "Post Your Answer" button to post things which are not answers. The protocol here is to upvote and perhaps star this question if you think it's useful and deserves attention.

Comment: In the meantime, "answer" posts which are not answers such as "Me too!" will get flagged as "not an answer" and eventually deleted, but removing this chaff requires effort from the site's regular users which could more fruitfully be spent on actually answering questions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no limit on the number of people with roles, the person you have selected for the Page Role must have Liked the page. If someone has not liked the page you can not give him/her page role.

Once the person like the page, you can use his/her name or username or email address to select them for Page Role.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work and you have to use the mobile fb app instead of the web page !